# how to input data into an arraylist for user defined class?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
for(i=0;i<in.length;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<in.length;j++)
        {
            //System.out.println("for"+in[i].val);
            //System.out.println("for "+in[j].val);
            if(comp(in[i].bin,in[j].bin,n)!=null)
            {
                String bi=comp(in[i].bin,in[j].bin,n);
                //System.out.println("is it null "+co[k]);
                coin.a(in[i],in[j],bi);//taken input
                co.add(coin);//now passing to array list HERE LIES THE PROBLEM!!!
                System.out.println(in[i].val+","+in[j].val+"="+coin.bin);
                in[i].combo=true;
                in[j].combo=true;
                k++;
            }   

        }
    }
```

55f96302address of coin 55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302
55f96302address of coin @55f96302

As you can see the reference of all elements in the list is same as that of "coin"
what should i do to solve this?

Comment: There is nothing called `element is pointing to memory block of "coin" variable` in Java!!! You have `coin` object of couple class and it'll definitely work like a charm!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Could you please try explain your use case. Also, in Java, classes should always be in `PascalCase` - so `Coin` not `coin`. That isn't helping the clarity of your answer.

Comment: can you put `couple` class.

Comment: What error you got? you can explain with more details what you want?

Comment: @shekharsuman I guess he means the reference to the object in memory.

Comment: @Tom-Yeah,I know but it has nothing to do with insertion in ArrayList. Actually, I guess he is still nostalgic with C-style coding...

Comment: @shekharsuman: Just a guess: he might tried to add the `coin` instance once. Called `coin.a()` again to take another input and then tried to add the new data to the list. But can't say for sure, due to that unclear question.

Comment: @Tom-Actually,`coin` would be better termed as an object,which can be easily added to ArrayList. Calling it an instance would be a mistake!!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you wouldn't have any issue having a references build over a collection of couple class. This is the right way on dealing with elements storage in java.

Comment: thank you for the answer but i have no idea what a collection is :(.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, your problem is that you do not want the item stored in the list to be the same element as the one stored in your variable `coin`. In this case, you should create an exact copy of the object stored in the variable `coin` and put the copy into the list.

In fact, you should always be careful when passing around mutable objects, e.g., putting them into a list. Otherwise, your program can become hard to debug. Search for **defensive copy in Java**.

I can think of two ways of creating a defensive copy: **cloning** and **copy constructor**. However, note that . [implementing Cloneable is not trivial](http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html).

Also, I would suggest you to think about whether and how you can make your class `couple` immutable. In most cases, the advantages of having an immutable class (i.e., not having to worry about defensive copying) outweight the disadvanteges (i.e., creating new objects, leading to a bit of a higher cost in memory and CPU cycles).

TL;DR: The only reason to not pass the same reference into the arraylist is that the item could potentially be modified by everyone that has access to it. Create a defensive copy or make your object immutable.

**Edit:** After you have updated your example, I see your problem (at least I think I do). I tried to reconstruct your example as a minimum working example. What you essentially have is:

```
public class Coin {

    int value;

    public Coin(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Coin myCoin = new Coin(0);
        List<Coin> bankAccount = new ArrayList<Coin>();
        for (int coinValue = 0; coinValue < 5; coinValue ++) {
            myCoin.setValue(coinValue);
            bankAccount.add(myCoin);
        }
        for(Coin coin : bankAccount)
            System.out.println(coin);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Coin: " + value;
    }

}
```

If you run this code, then all coins in the list will have value 4. The reason is, that the method `setValue` (which corresponds to your method `a`) mutates the `Coin` instance. The best way to solve this (if possible) is to make `Coin` immutable and return a new `Coin` instance when calling `setValue`. The code would look like this:

```
public class ImmutableCoin {

    final int value;

    public ImmutableCoin(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public ImmutableCoin setValue(int value) {
        return new ImmutableCoin(value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ImmutableCoin myCoin = new ImmutableCoin(0);
        List<ImmutableCoin> bankAccount = new ArrayList<ImmutableCoin>();
        for (int coinValue = 0; coinValue < 5; coinValue ++) {
            myCoin = myCoin.setValue(coinValue);
            bankAccount.add(myCoin);
        }
        for(ImmutableCoin coin : bankAccount)
            System.out.println(coin);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ImmutableCoin: " + value;
    }

}
```

Try running this code. You will now not have the same object inserted multiple times in your list.

If however, your method `a` **must** modify the object and is not allowed to return a new object, then you must make a copy of the object yourself in the loop, modify this copy, and then insert the copy. The code could look something like this:

```
public class MutableCoin {

    int value;

    public MutableCoin(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    // copy constructor
    public MutableCoin(MutableCoin toCopyFrom) {
        this.value = toCopyFrom.value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MutableCoin myCoin = new MutableCoin(0);
        List<MutableCoin> bankAccount = new ArrayList<MutableCoin>();
        for (int coinValue = 0; coinValue < 5; coinValue ++) {
            // make a copy
            myCoin = new MutableCoin(myCoin);
            myCoin.setValue(coinValue);
            bankAccount.add(myCoin);
        }
        for(MutableCoin coin : bankAccount)
            System.out.println(coin);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "MutableCoin: " + value;
    }

}
```

This will also work. I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you your answer is providing the most number of options..So i'll try it out and let you know. :)

Comment: i want that the elements of list to not change with changes in coin  so is there an immutable variant for ArrayList?

Comment: @SiddhantReddy Actually it depends on what you want: If your List is immutable, you cannot alter the List, i.e., if you want to add an element, then you create a new List from the first with the added element. If you want that the Data you put into your lists cannot be altered later, then you want this data (in your case, the class coin) to be immutable. I think in your case, you want the latter. But to answer your question on whether there is an immutable List: Look at the guava libraries: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html.